# Unity Android 6 Fragment$InstantiationException

Tags: android, exception, crash, unity-game-engine

recently (past few weeks maybe) most of the android 6 users of my app started to suffer from crashes. UnityPlayerActivity failed to start with exception logged: `android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException.`

Stack trace:

> **java.lang.RuntimeException:**
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
> android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java:0)
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>
> **Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException:**
> android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:628)
> android.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:106)
> android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1858)
> android.app.FragmentController.restoreAllState(FragmentController.java:122)
> android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:918)
> com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:0)
> android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)

Initially my first thought was permissions problem but I can't reproduce this error on any of my android 6 devices even if I deny permission (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).

Is there is any workaround for this problem(if this problem is a common for Unity on Android 6)?

Thanks in advance!

PS:
Unity version 5.5.0f3,
Android version from crush reports 6.0

Comment: What's your Unity version and the Android model? Just want to check if this is a know bug

Comment: All my apps are created with Unity 5.5.0f3. Android version from crush reports is 6.0

Comment: Sorry. The thing I can tell you is to update to 5.6.

Comment: @Programmer thanks anyway for checking out!

Comment: @Programmer on 5.6.1 we have same crashes on Android 6.0.

Comment: @Cyb do your use plugins FB, OneSignal, Prime31 or others with native code?

Comment: @acoolaum I use ad engine from Appodeal. As far as I understand my apk contains a lot of native plugins for different ad networks including Facebook.

Comment: The same crash for us Unity 5.6.1f1